# Can MD5 hashes be inconsistent on large files?

Tags: c#, md5

I am aware that MD5 hashes are not advisable for security any more but I have been using them as a checksum to make sure that a file has not been corrupted after a download/transfer, which I thought was still ok. Though after using this method on a file bigger than a gigabyte, I found that the stored and generated hashes did not match. This was after I had transferred it from one computer to another via a USB stick. I've searched online and found a couple of references to large files possibly creating inconsistent hashes but I didn't see anything conclusive.

I am using `ComputeHash(Stream inputStream)` of `MD5CryptoServiceProvider` to create the hash before and after transfer, so it should not be a case of the byte format being messed up between different languages or something. I also tried building the hash from the file again and the second time it seemed to create matching hashes fine. Did I just get unlucky and actually end up corrupting the file after copying it on and off the USB stick? Or is this a known problem with MD5 and I should ditch it completely? If so, what would be the best replacement that would ideally also be available as standard in C#, is SHA1 the next best option?

Comment: "large files possibly creating inconsistent hashes" would you care to share the links here? There are possible weaknesses in collisions or reversal, but for identical input data even very weak hash function always produces the same output, as it is always deterministic.

Comment: The first link I found was http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/problems-with-large-files-multi-gigabyte/c7beb33d-99a9-40e8-94ca-2133446fc63d that seemed to be something to do with moving between operating systems probably so I didn't want to jump to conclusions. There were a few other similar questions around but some of them could probably be down to user error, just thought I'd ask here before getting too deep into it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MD5 hash of some data will be *exactly* the same as a second MD5 hash of *exactly* the same data, regardless of the size of that data. The only problem with MD5 for large files is that, in some cases, you might get the same hash for two different files. This is ludicrously unlikely, though.

The same thing will apply for SHA1 and any other hash algorithm, though, since you're converting a large data-space down into a small hash-space.

It sounds significantly more likely that corruption occurred during the transfer, either on the USB bus or the flash device itself.

Comment: Both good answers but accepted this one for mentioning the likelihood of corruption. It happened again and this time just copying the file again fixed it, sounds like a dodgy USB stick or something.

Answer (score 5):

No, there is nothing wrong with MD5 for this purpose. **The hashes will always be identical**. There must be some difference in the file. You could use a binary diff tool, like one found in some hex editors to verify for yourself that something is different.

You can verify that your computations are correct by using another MD5 tool like [`md5sum`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/md5sum) or [HashTab](http://www.implbits.com/HashTab.aspx).

---

The reason MD5 is not recommended any more isn't that it doesn't work, or something like that. It's because the probabilty of a collision (generating the same hash for two different inputs) is high enough that an attacker could *intentionally* generate a collision to get around security features.

This is exactly what the [Flame malware did](http://trailofbits.files.wordpress.com/2012/06/flame-md5.pdf) to spoof a Microsoft signature.

Comment: A note on Flame: This is not the first time that attack has been used. It was demonstrated against SSL certificates in the mid-2000s, back when the MD5 collision problem was discovered.

Comment: @Polynomial you're correct. There are some historical notes in that PDF too.